# Unable to install React-chartjs-2 in React Parcel Project

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

Very simply by using the following command, I am unable to install React-chartJs-2 module in my React Parcel project:

```
npm install --save chart.js react-chartjs-2
```

After the installation when i started my project using (npm start), i getting the following error:

```
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'react-chartjs-2' from './src/pages/dashboard/quiz-detail.js'
```

My package.json after installation is looks like:

```
    {
  "name": "quizcopy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "description": "",
  "source": "/src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.10",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.1.0",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-export-table-to-excel": "^1.0.6",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-image-file-resizer": "^0.4.8",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.5.3",
    "swr": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: does `chartjs` appear in your package.json ?

Comment: do it like    npm i name_of_dependency --force   or do npm i --force

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena yes I tried but not getting the same :-(

Comment: @Johan now I added my package.json.

Comment: It appears. What happens if you do a `npm i` to reinstall all modules ? Do you get an error ?

Comment: try to check you node version and reaCT VERSION

Comment: make them with sync to each other